# c++ omp atomic capture - syntax?

Tags: c++, openmp

Very simple code, cannot see why compiler throws an error about my use of `omp atomic capture`

// my_class.h

```
class my_class
{

my_class()
{ }

static int class_int;
static int get_next_int();

};
```

// my_class.cpp

```
int my_class::get_next_int()
{
   int next_int;
  #pragma omp atomic capture
  next_int = class_int++;

  return next_int;
}
```

Compiler error:

```
my_class.cpp: In static member function 'static int 
my_class::get_next_int()':

my_class.cpp:2069: error: expected end of line before 'capture'
my_class.cpp:2070: error: invalid operator for '#pragma omp atomic' before '=' token
```

Might it have something to do with `static`?  I can't imagine why...

If I use `pragma omp critical` instead, then it works fine (no compiler error).

PS  I have  `#include <omp.h>`  in all .h and .cpp.   And I link with `-fopenmp` , as usual

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `capture` clause was introduced in OpenMP 3.1. You need a compliant compiler:

- GCC since v4.7
- Intel compilers since v10.1
- Oracle Solaris Studio since v12.3
- many [other compilers](http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-compilers/) except...
- MSVC (all versions, including 2012), which **does not support** OpenMP versions higher than 2.0.

GCC 4.4.5 does not support OpenMP 3.1. It only supports OpenMP 3.0.

Comment: Wow.  I should have check the obvious I suppose.  Obviously I assumed that `capture` was basic enough that the compiler/version didn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Microsoft compiler it does not support [clauses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ztckdts%28v=vs.100%29) to the `omp atomic` directive.

Change your code to just `#pragma omp atomic` and according to the ms docs the compiler will do the right thing.  Color me skeptical. :)

Comment: @CycoMatto: Does your gcc support the capture clause?  I see it mentioned in 4.8ish gcc changelogs. I have no Linux machine here to check anymore... :)